# DropdownList DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

Hi everyone I have problem about dropdown list. I am using dropdown list with datasource. How can I get that value which I selected ?

```
// I need a if statement here because my programme doesn't know which value of dropdown list selected and I don't know how to use this with datasource.

if(//if I select quiz 1 from dropdown list ,quiz 1 should list questions.)

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

string chooce = "Select Quiz from tblQuiz where Quiz=1 ";
SqlCommand userExist = new SqlCommand(chooce, con);
con.Open();
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

if (temp == 1)
{
    if (rbList.Items[0].Selected == true)
    {
        string cmdStr = "Select Question from tblQuiz where ID=1";
        SqlCommand quest = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
        lblque.Text = quest.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The code you listed doesn't really match the question you asked. We need to know the name/id of the drop down list, the type of datasource you used, and the way you bound the datasource to the drop down list in order to answer this effectively.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can bind the  DropDownList in different ways by using `List, Dictionary, Enum, DataSet DataTable`. 
Main you have to consider three thing while binding the datasource of a dropdown.

1. DataSource - Name of the dataset or datatable or your datasource
2. DataValueField - These field will be hidden
3. DataTextField - These field will be displayed on the dropdwon.

you can use following code to bind a dropdownlist to a datasource as a `datatable`:

```
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblQuiz", con);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "QUIZ_Name";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "QUIZ_ID"

    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

if you want to process on selection of dropdownlist, then you have to change `AutoPostBack="true"` you can use `SelectedIndexChanged` event to write your code.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strQUIZ_ID=DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    string strQUIZ_Name=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    // Your code..............
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        drpCategory.DataSource = CategoryHelper.Categories;
        drpCategory.DataTextField = "Name";
        drpCategory.DataValueField = "Id";
        drpCategory.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of an explanation would be good. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

Refer to example at this link. It may be help to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

     // Load data for the DropDownList control only once, when the 
     // page is first loaded.
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {

        // Specify the data source and field names for the Text 
        // and Value properties of the items (ListItem objects) 
        // in the DropDownList control.
        ColorList.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
        ColorList.DataTextField = "ColorTextField";
        ColorList.DataValueField = "ColorValueField";

        // Bind the data to the control.
        ColorList.DataBind();

        // Set the default selected item, if desired.
        ColorList.SelectedIndex = 0;

     }

  }

void Selection_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

     // Set the background color for days in the Calendar control
     // based on the value selected by the user from the 
     // DropDownList control.
     Calendar1.DayStyle.BackColor = 
         System.Drawing.Color.FromName(ColorList.SelectedItem.Value);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set the defaults for the dropdown.  Use selected value, but you have to set the selected value.  For instance, I populate the datasource with the name and id field for the table/list.  I set the selected value to the id field and the display to the name.  When I select, I get the id field.  I use this to search a relational table and find an entity/record.