# Best way to loop through SQL query results and add to a dropdownlist for each result in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a query that runs on page load. The results from the query are different every time so I need to be able to loop through the results in the dataReader, and for each result add an option to a dropdownlist (or Select list).

I know how to do this in MySQL, but I don't know how to do this in SQL server and Visual Basic.

The logic is:

```
For Each Result in Query.Results
    Add DropDownList.Option
End
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You know you can bind to a `DropDownList` right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource

Comment: What type is the `Result` variable?  What type is the `Query` variable? What does the `Add` method do?  What about it doesn't work?  There are not enough details in your question to make it answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do it the hard way when there is no looping required. All you need to do is add a DropDownList to your page and a DataSource and then wire then up similar to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="YourID" runat="server" 
  AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="YourDataSource"
  DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="VALUE" />


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="YourDataSource" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YOURCON %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT 
        NAME 
        ,VALUE
      FROM YourTable 
      ORDER BY NAME">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: This definitely looks like the easier way to go! Thanks!