# Code behind not taking the current text from dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my button and dropdown, when I click the button and a method is called in the code behind, the code behind is not taking the current text of the dropdown, but the text after the refresh of the site. The aspx code for this is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server" />
<div>
    <table runat="server" id="showDBTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="showDB" runat="server" OnClick="showDBContent" Text="Show database content" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="showDBDropDown" OnLoad="FindExistingMetaTag" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

and the code behind:

```
protected void showDBContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String queryString = "";
    if (showDBDropDown.Text == "Show all")
    {
        queryString = "SELECT * from dbo.Search";
    }
    else
    {
        queryString = "SELECT * from dbo.Search where Tag = '" + (showDBDropDown.Text).TrimStart().TrimEnd() + "'";
    }
```

How do I work around that?

Edit - As requested:

```
    protected void FindExistingMetaTag(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String queryString = "SELECT TAG from dbo.Tags";
    List<String> tagsShow = new List<String>();
    tagsShow.Add("Show all");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(info.connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = queryString;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tagsShow.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }

    showDBDropDown.DataSource = tagsShow;
    showDBDropDown.DataBind();
    showDBDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I just noticed it might have been "showDBDropDown.SelectedIndex = 0;", but it does not seem to change anything to remove it.

Comment: Can you add your FindExistingMetaTag logic?

Comment: @MatiasP show us your  code where you are populating your `dropdownlist `

Comment: My assumption is that when the page does its postback, the drop down list is being cleared and repopulated, causing you to lose the previously selected item. You may need to add some code checks to make sure the list is not re-instantiated on postback.

Comment: That does sound quite logical, but how do I do that?

FindExistingMetaTag add

Comment: I do hope someone will create tag with name '; drop table Tags;--

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `OnLoad` property from `showDBDropDown`:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="showDBDropDown" />
```

and populate the content of `showDBDropDown` in `Page_Load` method at first load like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDropdowns();
    }
}

private void BindDropdowns()
{
    String queryString = "SELECT TAG from dbo.Tags";
    List<String> tagsShow = new List<String>();
    tagsShow.Add("Show all");
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(info.connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = queryString;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tagsShow.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }

    showDBDropDown.DataSource = tagsShow;
    showDBDropDown.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with `yourDropdown.SelectedItem.Text` or `yourDropdown.SelectedItem.Value` according to your need.

```
if (showDBDropDown.SelectedItem.Text== "Show all")
{
    queryString = "SELECT * from dbo.Search";
}
else
{
    queryString = "SELECT * from dbo.Search where Tag = '" +    
                        (showDBDropDown.SelectedItem.Text) + "'";
}
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource/14105600#14105600) for more about `DropdownList`