# SQL Query only returns one item (rather than complete list) - asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an SQL query within ASP.NET, but it only seems to return 1 result rather than filling the list with 4 as it should (as the query itself is correct)

Code:

```
List<string> dropItems, dropItems2;

using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    dropItems = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<String>(
        String.Format("SELECT locations.Code FROM locations")).ToList();
}
using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    dropItems2 = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<String>(
        String.Format("SELECT locations.Name FROM locations")).ToList();
}
```

After the code executes, each list only contains one item rather than 4 which they both should

F.Y.I - The item I'm always receiving rather than the full 4 is just the last one

Comment: I don't know if this could be the reason, but in the MS example I found, there is no `String.Format` in the code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx . Which of the four items do you receive? Is it always the first item?

Comment: Always the last item

Answer (score -1):

using .ToList() makes a list of what the query returns (lets call it a query result object). since a query only returns one result objects the list is only 1 long.

An easier way to fill a dropdownList is to use its datasource. A example can be found here: [DropdownList DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource)

Comment: When I run the query in HediSQL, the same query returns 4 results. But when the above code is executed only 1 result is returned

Comment: There is a difference between the SQL results and a dbContext.Database.Sqlquery result. The SQL result is inside the sqlQuery result. And you are creating a list of sqlQuery results.

Comment: What modification to the above code would you suggest in order to get it to complete the function described correctly?