# How to get text value of a selected item in drop down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i am trying to get text of a value being selected in drop down list but it doesn't  display value but '-Select-'

**Code:**

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["Response"])) {   
                String InvoiceNo= Convert.ToString(ViewState["InvoiceNo"]);
                String ConductorName = Convert.ToString(DropDownListConductors.SelectedItem.Text);

                Response.Redirect("~/ManageTransport/ConductorSlip.aspx?InvoiceNo=" + InvoiceNo+"&ConductorName="+ConductorName);
            }
        }
```

DDL:

```
DropDownListConductors.DataSource = ManageTransport.ManageConductorDevices.GetConductors();
             DropDownListConductors.DataTextField = "Name";
             DropDownListConductors.DataValueField = "ConductorID";
             DropDownListConductors.DataBind();
             DropDownListConductors.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-Select-", "0"));
```

ConductorSlip.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            ConductorName = Request.QueryString["ConductorName"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

.aspx

```
<tr>
    <td>Conductor Name</td>
    <td><%=ConductorName %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where is your dropdown list code ? What values you are binding to the list ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource/14105600#14105600

Answer (score 3):

Update you code :

```
String ConductorName = Convert.ToString(DropDownListConductors.SelectedItem.Text);
```

to

for selecting value

```
 String ConductorName = DropDownListConductors.SelectedValue;
```

for selecting text

```
 String ConductorName = DropDownListConductors.SelectedItem.Text;
```

For more information [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource/14105600#14105600)

Comment: doesn't work, it gives me int value that i assigned in databse

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use Conver.ToString() because the Text property is already a String.

See the code below:-

```
string ConductorName = DropDownListConductors.SelectedItem.Text;
```