# Populate Text boxes based on drop down list in 3 tier application

Tags: c#, asp.net, 3-tier

I would like to populate my text boxes with values based on the selection from my drop down list.

**DAL:**

```
public static string GetTicket(collection b)
{
    try
    {

        string returnValue = string.Empty;
        DB = Connect();
        DBCommand = connection.Procedure("getTicket");
        DB.AddInParameter(DBCommand, "@SupportRef", DbType.String, b.SupportRef1);

        var myReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            returnValue = myReader.GetString(0);
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

**BLL:**

```
   public string returnTicket(collection b)
   {
       try
       {
           string ticket = DAL.data.GetTicket(b);
           return ticket;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   }
```

**PL:**

```
protected void ddl_Customers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = ddl_Customers.SelectedValue.ToString();

    //populate the text boxes
    txtSupportRef.Text = bobj.returnTicket(selectedValue);
}
```

My Stored Procedure has got a variable called SupportRef which needs a value before it can return results.

I get the following errors:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'BLL.business.returnTicket(DAL.collection)' 
has some invalid arguments
```

AND

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'DAL.collection'
```

Comment: you're passing a string and not an object of collection..?

Comment: from the form i am passing in a string value

Comment: Please post the structure of the class `DAL.collection`. That way we can help you to convert from type `string` to type `DAL.collection`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource/14105600#14105600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

In your presentation layer, map the `string` type into the `DAL.collection` type. [You can see this here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TccE1Z)

```
protected void ddl_Customers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = ddl_Customers.SelectedValue.ToString();

    // map the string to a DAL.collection
    var collection = new DAL.collection();
    collection.SupportRef1 = selectedValue;

    //populate the text boxes
    txtSupportRef.Text = bobj.returnTicket(collection);
}
```

## Explanation

Both of the errors are compilation errors. You can see a [recreation of them both in this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9UkF4D).

### Error 1

> The best overloaded method match for 'BLL.business.returnTicket(DAL.collection)' has some invalid arguments

The compiler is trying to find a method called `BLL.business.returnTicket` that takes a single argument. In the match that it finds, the method takes a single `DAL.collection` argument. You're passing it a `string` instead, which is an invalid argument, because a `string` is not a `DAL.collection`. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Overload resolution is a compile-time mechanism for selecting the best function member to invoke given an argument list and a set of candidate function members.

### Error 2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'DAL.collection'

Since `BLL.business.returnTicket` takes a `DAL.collection` argument, the compiler tries to convert the `string` into a `DAL.collection`. It fails because there is no *implicit conversion* from a `string` type to a `DAL.collection` type. [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx):

> Implicit conversions: No special syntax is required because the conversion is type safe and no data will be lost.

### What to do?

There are a few approaches you could take, in order of complexity.

1. In your presentation layer, map the `string` type to the `DAL.collection` type. Recommended.
2. In your business layer, create a new `returnTicket(string)` method overload, in addition to the existing one, which maps the `string` to the `DAL.collection` class. Recommended.
3. Change both `returnTicket(DAL.collection)` and `GetTicket(DAL.collection)` to take a `string` instead of a `DAL.collection`. This has two downsides: it will break other code that currently calls those methods with a `DAL.collection` argument and it requires changing four lines of code in two different methods.
4. Create a [user-defined conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) from `string` into `DAL.collection.` Downside: this is likely overkill.

#### Recommended things to do

In your presentation layer, convert or to map the `string` type into the `DAL.collection` type. That is what the short answer above accomplishes.

Alternatively, in your business layer, create a new `returnTicket(string)` method overload, *in addition* to the existing method. It would look like this.

```
public string returnTicket(collection b)
{
     // map the string to a DAL.collection
     var collection = new DAL.collection();
     collection.SupportRef1 = selectedValue;

     // call the existing method that takes a DAL.collection
     returnTicket(b);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, From the Form you are trying to pass an String value to the Business layer method returnTicket(collection b). But in this Business layer method returnTicket(collection b) signature has the collection type argument to be accepted.
After selecting the value from the dropdown, the selected value is stored in the string variable.
Please change the collection type of the BLL and DAL's method to the string type. 
This change will resolve the above error.

Comment: While this does work, it will break other code that already calls `GetTicket(collection b)` or `returnTicket(collection b)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `string` type argument to `returnTicket of BLL` and `GetTicket of DAL`.Change your methods like this

**BLL**

```
public string returnTicket(string supportRef)
{
   try
   {
       string ticket = DAL.data.GetTicket(supportRef);
       return ticket;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw ex;
   }
}
```

**DAL**

```
public static string GetTicket(string supportRef)
{
 try
 {

    string returnValue = string.Empty;
    DB = Connect();
    DBCommand = connection.Procedure("getTicket");
    DB.AddInParameter(DBCommand, "@SupportRef", DbType.String, supportRef);

    var myReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        returnValue = myReader.GetString(0);
    }

    return returnValue;
 }


 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    throw ex;
 }

}
```

Comment: While this does work, it will break other code that already calls `GetTicket(collection b)` or `returnTicket(collection b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string from Presentation Layer. Try passing the `collection` in presentation layer.