# Dropdownlist Bind from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a two `Dropdownlist` control in my form. I fill one `Dropdownlist` from database. Why does it fill value in both `Dropdownlist` controls?

Here is what I have done.

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="false" Style="position: static" ID="ddlcountry" OnSelectedIndexChanged="country_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>


public void Bind_ddlCountry()
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id,name from country order by id", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds != null)
            {
                ddlcountry.Items.Clear();
                ddlcountry.DataSource = ds;
                ddlcountry.DataTextField = (ds.Tables[0].Columns["name"].ToString());
                ddlcountry.DataValueField = (ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString());
                ddlcountry.DataBind();
                ddlcountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Country", "0"));
                ds.Dispose();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I call this Bind_ddlCountry() on page load. This bind perfectly.

But I have one more Dropdown list in this form

```
<asp:DropDownList Style="position: static" AutoPostBack="false" ID="ddlPhone" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>


 public void Bind_ddlPhone()
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id,phonecode from country", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            if (ds != null)
            {
                ddlPhone.Items.Clear();
                ddlPhone.DataSource = ds;
                ddlPhone.DataTextField = (ds.Tables[0].Columns["phonecode"].ToString());
                ddlPhone.DataValueField = (ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ToString());
                ddlPhone.DataBind();
                ddlPhone.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Phone", "0"));
                ds.Dispose();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

This also fill with old data means ddlcountry data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your complete html and related code behind code for batter understanding.

Comment: use different `DataSource` second time like you can try by replacing `ds` to `ds1` in  `public void Bind_ddlPhone()` this method.

Comment: @Rahul Hendawe.. I tried it but same problem.

Comment: update your question what did you change exactly.

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource/14105600#14105600

Answer (score 0):

change the cmd, da and ds name 
as

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select id,phonecode from country", conn);
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
da2.Fill(ds2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different methods. 'new' keyword  creates a new instance of that object in that method,  so  renaming your fields it's not the way.

Check your table. I believe that you have the same data in 'phonecode' and 'name' columns.

Also, your approach is to long.
You can change DataTextField and DataValueField  like this:

```
            ddlPhone.DataTextField = "phonecode";
            ddlPhone.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlPhone.DataBind();

 ddlcountry.DataTextField = "name";
            ddlcountry.DataValueField = "id";
            ddlcountry.DataBind();
```

To be sure that you have disposed everything use using.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select aaa,bbb From TableName", conn))
    {//databind code}
```