# How to make my combo show data from two tables

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MDI C# code that reads and writes in and out of a sql DB. I have a "projects" form that has a "Companies" filed (combo) which should be read from the table companies. Now, for some other reason, I have another table which contains the name of some companies with different nature (and that is why they are in a separate table). Now I am wondering if it would be possible if I can have the company names from both of those tables in my project form. Do I need to changes the companies filed to a Listview? Do I have to change the SQL? I am pretty confused on this one. Can someone help? Please!

Comment: You can achieve this using `SELECT` statement with `UNION` option between those two tables. (if you use `SQL SERVER` as your back-end)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource/14105600#14105600

Comment: Thank you very much, for both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName FROM table2
GO
```

Refer: [UNION & UNION ALL Diff.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: Great!! Glad it worked!