# How do I put Dropdownbox DataValueField value into variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the value from DropDownlist.DataValueField to the contact_id variable so i can then read the rest of the data of the id selected from the dropdownlist. This is my example code:

```
string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string com = "Select * from Product";
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Product_Name";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Id";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

            String contact_id = DropDownList1.DataValueField.Trim();

            Textbox1.Text = contact_id;
```

I expect the value in dropdownlist1.DataValueField to be kept in contact_id variable. But instead, nothing shows up in Textbox1.

Comment: The solution for these types of problems are well documented. Maybe you could learn from the documentation :)

Comment: Are you sure there should be something in contact_id variable if you don't select any value yet? You've binded a list of values but the value is not selected.

Comment: Sorry, i did some test and found out it was my mistake... gonna rewrite the question problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SelectedValue property…

```
// set
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "1";
// get
string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: That wont work... Im using database to populate the Dropdownlist1. ur solution would work for simple dropdownlist...

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource

Comment: Sorry, i did some test and found out it was my mistake... gonna rewrite the question problem